# Error in the below CSS code while designing drop-downmenu-bar?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build the navigation menu-bar with css and something went wrong but could not able to figure what is it..??

The html code is :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS3 drop down</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

            <ul> <!--sub_menu of About to be build-->
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
            </ul>

        <li><a href="#">Cases</a></li>
            <ul> <!--sub_menu of Cases to be build-->
                <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is this :-

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
}

/*Determing the margin ,,centering the drop down menu on the page*/

ul.menu {
     margin : 150px auto 0 auto;
}

/* menu */
.menu {
     height : 60px;
     width : 550px;
     background: #e3e3e3;
     border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu li {
     display: block;
     height: 60px;
     float: left;
     list-style: none;
     position: relative;
}

/*All the links to be displayed*/
.menu li a {
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: black;
     font-size: 17px;
     padding: 0 18px;
     margin: 10px 0;
     line-height: 50px;
     border-left: 1px groove #d6d6d6;
     border-right: 1px groove #d6d6d6;
     transition: color.8s;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left:none; }
.menu li:last-child a { border-right:none; }

/*changing color on hover*/
.menu li:hover > a {
     color: red;
}

/*Sub menu*/
.menu ul {
     /*opacity: 0;*/
     position: absolute;
     top: 60px;
     background-color: red;
     }
```

pLz give clear explanation what r the main problems..!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Basic problem is with your HTML Code..

while making menu or submenu use the `<ul>` under `<li>`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS3 drop down</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
           <ul class="submenu"> <!--sub_menu of About to be build-->
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
        <li><a href="#">Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cases</a>
            <ul class="submenu"> <!--sub_menu of Cases to be build-->
                <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 6</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope rest you can take care yourself. here is the Demo link for you.

http://jsbin.com/zokiboce/1/edit